# Cannot click Image into Preview Repsonsive Filemanager

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, responsive-design

I have a problem When I am using Responsive File Manager in Standalone , the problem came when I want to Double click Image from dialog Responsive file manager then append into Preview DIV.

here my code to call responsive filemanager

```
<a href="http://domain.com/assets/backend/lib/rf/filemanager/dialog.php?type=1&amp;popup=1&amp;field_id=backgroundName" class="btn iframe-btn" type="button">Select Picture</a>
```

script is included is

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{base_url()}}assets/backend/lib/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{base_url()}}assets/backend/lib/rf/filemanager/plugin.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{base_url()}}assets/backend/lib/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js?v=1.3.4"></script>

$(function(){
      $('.iframe-btn').fancybox({
      'width'   : 880,
      'height'  : 570,
      'type'    : 'iframe',
      'autoScale'   : false
      });
      $('#download-button').on('click', function() {
        ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'download-buttons');
      });
      $('.toggle').click(function(){
        var _this=$(this);
        $('#'+_this.data('ref')).toggle(200);
        var i=_this.find('i');
        if (i.hasClass('icon-plus')) {
          i.removeClass('icon-plus');
          i.addClass('icon-minus');
        }else{
          i.removeClass('icon-minus');
          i.addClass('icon-plus');
        }
      });
});
```

the error is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of null at include.min.js line 11
```

Here my jsfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/viyancs/LQG36/

anyone can help me this ?

resource 
http://responsivefilemanager.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I found the solution

don't user query `&popup=1` in iframe mode , I am change to this

```
<a href="http://domain.com/assets/backend/lib/rf/filemanager/dialog.php?type=1&amp;field_id=backgroundName" class="btn iframe-btn" type="button">Select Picture</a>
```

Now it's work

Answer (score 0):

1. If you used document.write();

In JavaScript document.write () is currently being parsed information can be used to write documents, and containing the code that calls this method in the place  tag puts the text in an HTML document.

only in the top-level code  tag document.write () can be called, which will document this script because it is run as part of the parsing process.

```
<html>
<body>

<script>
document.write("Hello");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

2.and.... I think... you checked include.min.js file import.

Comment: now I don't have much time for checking that, it's minified code and that is library from my plugins, I am looking for people that have same problem maybe , if you know for solve this I am really appreciated.